# Algorithm for incomplete ranking with imprecise comparisons

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph-algorithm

### SUMMARY

I'm looking for an algorithm to rank objects. Two objects can be compared. However, the comparisons are real world comparisons that may be flawed. Also, I care more about finding out the very best object than which ones are the worst.

### TO MOTIVATE:

Think that I'm scientifically evaluating materials. I combine two materials. I want to find the best working material for in-depth testing. So, I don't care about materials that are unpromising. However, each test can be a false positive or have anomalies between those particular two materials.

### PRECISE PROBLEM:

1. There is an unlimited pool of objects.
2. Two objects can be compared to each other. It is resource expensive to compare two objects.
3. It's resource expensive to consider an additional object. So, an object should only be included in the evaluation if it can be fully ranked.
4. It is very important to find the very best object  in the pool of the tested ones. If an object is in the bottom half, it doesn't matter to find out where in the bottom half it is. The importance of finding out the exact rank is a gradient with the top much more important.
5. Most of the time, if A > B and B > C, it is safe to assume that A > C. Sometimes, there are false positives. Sometimes A > B and B > C and C > A. This is not an abstract math space but real world measurements.
6. At the start, it is not known how many comparisons are allowed to be taken. The algorithm is granted permission to do another comparison until it isn't. Thus, the decision on including an additional object or testing more already tested objects has to be made.

### TO MOTIVATE MORE IN-DEPTH:

Imagine that you are tasked with hiring a team of boxers. You know nothing about evaluating boxers but can ask two boxers to fight each other. There is an unlimited number of boxers in the world. But it's expensive to fly them in. Ideally, you want to hire the n best boxers. Realistically, you don't know if the boxers are going to accept your offer. Plus, you don't know how competitively the other boxing clubs bid. You are going to make offers to only the best n boxers, but have to be prepared to know which next n boxers to send offers to. That you only get the worst boxers is very unlikely.

### SOME APPROACHES

I could think of the following approaches. However, they all have drawbacks. I feel like there should be a much better approach.

1. USE TRADITIONAL SORTING ALGORITHMS

Traditional sorting algorithms could be used.

Drawback:
 - A false positive could serious throw of the correctness of the algorithm.
 - A sorting algorithm would spend half the time sorting the bottom half of the pack, which is unimportant.
 - Sorting algorithms start with all items. With this problem, we are allowed to do the first test, not knowing if we are allowed to do a second test. We may end up only being allowed to do two test. Or we may be allowed to do a million tests.

2. USE TOURNAMENT ALGORITHMS
   There are algorithms for tournaments. E.g., everyone gets a first match. The winner of the first match moves on to the next round. There is a variety of tournament strategies that accounts for people having a bad day or being paired with the champion in their first match.

Drawback:
 - This seems pretty promising. The difficulty is to find one that allows adding one more player at a time as we are allowed more comparisons. It seems that there should be a highly specialized solution that's better than a standard tournament algorithm.

3. BINARY SEARCH
   We could start with two objects. Each time an object is added, we could use a binary search to find its spot in the ranking. Because the top is more important, we could use a weighted binary search. E.g. instead of testing the mid point, it tests the point at the top 1/3.

Drawback:
 - The algorithm doesn't correct for false positives. If there is a false positive at the top early on, it could skew the whole rest of the tests.

4. COUNT WINS AND LOSSES
   The wins and losses could be counted. The algorithm would choose test subjects by a priority of the least losses and second priority of the most wins. This would focus on testing the best objects. If an object has zero losses, it would get the focus of the testing. It would either quickly get a loss and drop in priority, or it would get a lot more tests because it's the likely top candidate.

DRAWBACK:
 - The approach is very nice in that it corrects for false positives. It also allows adding more objects to the test pool easily. However, it does not consider that a win against a top object counts a lot more than a win against a bottom object. Thus, comparisons are wasted.

5. GRAPH
   All the objects could be added to a graph. The graph could be flattened.

DRAWBACK:
 - I don't know how to flatten such a messy graph that could have cycles and ambiguous end nodes. There could be multiple objects that are undefeated. How would one pick a winner in such a messy graph? How would one know which comparison would be the most valuable?

6. SCORING
   As a win depends on the rank of the loser, a win could be given a score. Say A > B, means that A gets 1 point. if C > A, C gets 2 points because A has 1 point. In the end, objects are ranked by how many points they have.

DRAWBACK
 - The approach seems promising in that it is easy to add new objects to the pool of tested objects. It also takes into account that wins against top objects should count for more. I can't think of a good way to determine the points. That first comparison, was awarded 1 point. Once 10,000 objects are in the pool, an average win would be worth 5,000 points. The award of both tests should be roughly equal. Later comparisons overpower the earlier comparisons and make them be ignored when they shouldn't.

Does anyone have a good idea on tackling this problem?

Comment: Do comparisons have a fixed probability of failure, or is the best ranked boxer more likely to compare favourably, especially when for example compared to the weakest?

Comment: I'm not quite sure of your question. The best ranked boxer is more likely to win against the weakest ranked boxer. But the currently best ranked boxer may not be the actually best ranked boxer. The boxer could have gotten lucky or could have had a specific advantage over the last opponent.

Answer (score 0):

I would search for an easily computable value for an object, that could be compared between objects to give a good enough approximation of order. You could compare each new object with the current best accurately, then insertion sort the loser into a list of the rest using its computed value.

The best will always be accurate. The ordering of the rest depending on your "value".

Comment: I don't have an "easily computable value for an object." 

This isn't an algorithm that simply runs on a chip. Each comparison requires a scientific sampling outside of the computer to be taken.

Comment: Maybe I should have said *more* easily computable value. I answered because I have a similar problem where the cost of getting full data for comparison is 100,000 times the cost of the estimation value I have to use. We continuously try and think of ways to improve the accuracy of our estimation value.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into Elo Rating systems and its derivatives. (like Glicko, BayesElo, WHR, TrueSkill etc.)

So you assign each object a preliminary rating, and then update that value according to the matches/comparisons you make. (with bigger changes to the ratings the more unexpected the outcome was)

This still leaves open the question of how to decide which object to compare to which other object to gain most information. For that I suggest looking into tournament systems and playoff formats. Though I suspect that an optimal solution will be decidedly more ad-hoc than that.